# How can we export a variable from a Generator function in SAGA?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

```
export function* getContacts(action: PayloadAction<SearchQuery>) {
  const stationCode = action.payload.stationCode;
  console.log(stationCode);////// Want stationCode from here to outside 
  const requestURL = `${API_PATH}contacts/departments/${stationCode}`;
  const requestOptions = {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    method: 'GET',
  };
  try {
    yield put(actions.setIsLoading(true));
    let contactList = yield call(request, requestURL, requestOptions);
    transformContacts(contactList);
    yield put(actions.setContactRecords(contactList));
    yield put(actions.setIsLoading(false));
  } catch (err: any) {
    let errorObject: ErrorObject = { status: err.status, message: '' };
    if (err.status === 400) {
      errorObject.message = 'Invalid Station Code';
    } else {
      errorObject.message =
        'We are observing a technical issue...Please try again later';
    }
    yield put(actions.loadStationsError(errorObject));
    yield put(actions.setIsLoading(false));
  }
  // return stationCode;
}
```

How can I export stationscode from there to another component ? export is not working
EG : export const stationCode = action.payload.stationCode not Working

Comment: you can't export a variable from within a function, exports can only exist at the root of the module

Comment: You can't really export from within the function. You need to store payload value somewhere in store and use selector to get it in your component.

Comment: Why do you want to export `stationCode` from a saga?

Comment: Yes now got it ..thank you